# DelphiXE5 X Permissão Administrador

Tags: delphi

Preciso rodar um programa em Delphi como Administrador, eu já coloquei o arquivo de manifesto, e mesmo assim ele não funciona, segue o meu arquivo de manifesto.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="MyApp" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
        processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Windows Vista application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--Windows 7-->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!--Windows Vista-->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>   
</assembly>
```

Estou tentando rodar da seguinte forma:

```
  {$R *.res}
  {$R UAC.res}
```

Se eu retirar esta linha, e deixar somente a do UAC.RES o programa funciona perfeitamente.

> {$R *.res}

Alguma sugestão ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seu manifest está Ok, aparentemente. Lembrou de setar o manifest nas configurações da aplicação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu fiz isso eu segui o seguinte tutorial(fonte): 
http://www.devmedia.com.br/delphi-xe2-executando-automaticamente-privilegios-de-administrador/25125

Espero ter ajudado. Abraço!

Comment: Obrigado @Rafael_Lima, resolvido!

Answer (score 0):

Deixe apenas:
  {$R *.res}

Vocês esta chamando duas vezes o UAC.RES, no "*" e na chamada direta "{$R UAC.res}", por isso deu o erro.